# Simplification of Multi-variable Big-O Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, runtime, big-o, complexity-theory

I am attempting to calculate the Time Complexity of a function that sorts two arrays using Merge sort, finds their intersection and sorts the result from this intersection.

By analyzing the steps involved, I found the key steps to have time complexities of

`O(a log a) + O(b log b) + O(a + b) + O((a+b)log(a+b))`

where `a` is the size of the first array and `b` is the size of the second array

I further simplified this down to:
`O(a log a) + O(b log b) + O((a+b)log(a+b))`

This is where I got stuck. But from what I have read, the idea of `a + b` being greater than both `a` and `b` allow me to remove the terms `a log a` and `b log b`. Using this, I got the overall Big O Notation as `O((a+b)log(a+b))`.

I am not sure if this is entirely correct though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. Let me explain it more explicitly step by step if you are not sure about it.

Overall time complexity is: `O(alog(a)) + O(blog(b)) + O(alog(a+b) + blog(a+b))`. 
Logarithm is a **strictly increasing function** on `x > 0`, that is, `log(x) > log(y)` iff `x > y > 0`. 
Input size cannot be negative, therefore for our analysis we can use this fact.

Using this property, we know that `log(a+b) > log(a)`, therefore `alog(a+b) > alog(a)`. 
We can conclude that `O(a log(a))` is a **subset** of `O(a log(a+b))` since **every** algorithm upper-bounded by `alog(a)` as input size goes to infinity is also upper-bounded by `a log(a+b)`.  
Therefore we can get rid of `O(a log(a))`.
Apply the same logic for `O(b log(b))`.

At the end, we have `O(alog(a+b) + blog(a+b))`, which corresponds to `O((a+b)log(a+b))`.